# Make symbol index with description

Tags: indexing

I'm starting to make a symbol and subject index with the package `multind`. In the symbol index, I would like to group the symbols by thematics, e.g., write **set theory notation** and have all the symbols below the description, after write **operators** and have all the notation for the operators, etc.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

I would like to obtain something like the following
[image]

Can anyone help me with a minimal working example? Preferably changing the section with page number.

Comment: The package `multind` is very old and unmaintained. I suggest you to use either `imakeidx` or `splitidx` to generate multiple indexes.

Comment: This seems more a work for the `glossaries` package.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to do this. I assume you either want to sort your symbols according to definition or to usage since symbols are difficult to sort alphabetically (and your sample isn't alphabetically sorted). With `glossaries` you can use the package option `sort=def` to sort in order of definition or `sort=use` to sort according to usage. In the example below, I've used `sort=def` (change `\setglossarystyle` to `\glossarystyle` if you are using a version of `glossaries` prior to version 4.0):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[nomain,section,sort=def]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

% (Pre glossaries v4.0 requires \glossarystyle rather than
% \setglossarystyle)
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
\renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{\dotfill}

\newglossary[op-glg]{operators}{op-gls}{op-glo}{Operators}
\newglossary[cn-glg]{constants}{cn-gls}{cn-glo}{Constants}

\makeglossaries

% Define a command to define operators
% Syntax: \newoperator[options]{label}{operator symbol}

\newcommand*{\newoperator}[3][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{type=operators,%
    name={$#3$},text={#3},description={},#1}%
}

% Similarly for constants

\newcommand*{\newconstant}[3][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{type=constants,%
    name={$#3$},text={#3},description={},#1}%
}

% Define operators

\newoperator{Mop}{\mathcal{M}}
\newoperator{Aalpha}{A_\alpha}
\newoperator{nablaOmega}{\nabla_\Omega}
\newoperator{T}{T}
\newoperator{I2}{I_2}
\newoperator{Jz}{J_z}
\newoperator{Gz}{G_z}

% Define constants

\newconstant{pdash}{p'}
\newconstant{jnu}{j_\nu}
\newconstant{Mcn}{\mathfrak{M}}
\newconstant{Dpq}{D_{p,q}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}

Some sample usage of constants:
\[
 \gls{pdash}, \gls{Mcn}, \gls{jnu}
\]

Some sample usage of operators:
\[
  \gls{Mop}, \gls{Aalpha}, \gls{nablaOmega}
\]

\newpage

More sample usage:
\[
\gls{T}, \gls{I2}, \gls{Jz}, \gls{Gz},
\gls{Mcn}, \gls{Dpq}, \gls{jnu}
\]

\chapter*{Index}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

In order to build the PDF you need to do:

1. Run `pdflatex`
2. Run `makeglossaries`
3. Run `pdflatex`

The above example produces:

Page 1:

[image: Image of page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Image of page 2]

Page 3:

[image: Image of page 3]

In your example image, you have some lines with multiple entries (for example, `c, c_1, c_2, \ldots, v_n`). There are various ways to deal with these. You could designate the first in the list (e.g, `c`) as the main parent entry, and the remainder as sub-entries, and then define a glossary style that puts the sub-entry names after the parent entry name, but this will complicate the location list. However, I think the easiest solution is probably to define an entry with the specified list and then use `\glsdisp` or `\glslink` whenever you use it.

For example:

```
\newconstant{c}{c, c_1, c_2, \ldots, v_n}
```

Then in the document:

```
In-line: $\glslink{c}{c}$ or $\glslink{c}{c_1}$ or $\glslink{c}{c_2}$ etc.
```